# Is it possible to automate the execution of a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, automation

I am thinking about, if it's possible to automate a chrome extension. I have a Chrome Extension with which I need to interact manually (e.g. click on it to extract some data from a website). I like to get rid of this manually clicking and execute the extension automatically.

Does anybody have an idea of how to approach this?

Comment: There's no specific API so it depends on the extension. In general, you can use external automation tools like AutoIt, AutoHotkey, Puppeteer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The extension is used for web scraping.

Comment: Then it's better to find a standalone utility for web scraping that can be inherently automated.